# Run function after registration in Laravel 5.3 basic authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

By default Laravel 5.3 login user automatically after registration.I need a suggestion for get the user ID after the user automatically logged in and then run a function without redirection.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `create()` method in `Auth\RegisterController.php` and call your function there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried some methods as you said but still not working.Please can you provide an example code snippet.Really appreciate.

Comment: I don't know how you function looks like, but if you have an object with method, just put something like this `(new YourObject)->yourMethod();` somewhere in `Auth\RegisterController@create` method.